# Self-hosting Wordpress blog on my NodeJS-based environment

Tags: node.js, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk backend running NodeJS. Since I don't want to use Wordpress to host it, I want to host a Wordpress blog on this pre-existing infrastructure.

Is it possible to host a Wordpress site using NodeJS?

Comment: I've edited your question for clarity. If you feel I haven't captured the essence of your question correctly, please feel free to edit on top of mine.

Comment: Thank you @esqew for editing the question.